# python re.split function, how do I return the full character set?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to use a regex pattern split this string into chunks seperated by any character.

```
s = 'a12b56c1'
import re
print(re.split('[a-zA-Z]',s))
```

This prints `['', '12', '56', '1']`

How do I use the split function to have it output the whole string, delimited by any character? IE `['a12', 'b56', 'c1']`

Comment: You shouldn't be using split then, you need something like `findall` or `finditer`, then adjust your regex to include what should be matched next

Comment: "I'm trying to use a regex pattern split this string into chunks seperated by any character.... IE `['a12', 'b56', 'c1']`" I can't understand this description. I think the output should instead be `['a', '12', 'b', '56', 'c', '1']`. Why is that wrong?

Comment: Splitting can be done at [`(?!\d)\B(?<=\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/EjAvSL/1) but the provided answer is more efficient.

Comment: What about input like `aaa12`?

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)', s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `re.findall` instead `re.split` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rkFInD/1)):

```py
s = "a12b56c1"
import re

print(re.findall(r"\D+\d+", s))
```

Prints:

```
['a12', 'b56', 'c1']
```